# Application Insights Does not show the data in azure portal?

Tags: windows, azure, windows-phone-8.1, azure-application-insights

When Application Insights are added to project successfully and send the data to azure portal.
But did not show any data In azure Portal.getting message learn how to get the data in all fields.
What can I do for getting data in portal....?

Comment: Have you confirmed that tracking data is sent to the portal via something like fiddler?

Answer (score 0):

Have you uncommented/wrote the next line

```
    Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsAppInitializer.InitializeAsync(
    Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsCollectors.Metadata |
    Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsCollectors.Session);
```

in the App method within the App.xaml.cs file? I forgot that the first time and went bananas as I didn't see any App Insights data on Azure.